# How to add, update, delete and search records in JavaFX+mysql jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview, fxml

having problems with how to add records,update record,delete record,search for record in tableview with scene builder in javafx netbeans with mysql jdbc...
Here are my codes on how I insert, update, delete and search into mysql jdbc...but not the table cause that is the problem i'm facing right now (insert new record, update them, delete them and search for records in tableview in javafx netbeans using scene builder)

```
//mycotroller...
package fxapplication;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author PHILSERVER
 */
public class SearchController implements Initializable {

     @FXML
    private Connection con;

     @FXML
    private Statement stmt;

      @FXML
    private ResultSet rs;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox cbGender;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfLocation;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfFirstname;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfSearch;

    @FXML
    private Button update;

    @FXML
    private Button insert;

    @FXML
    private Button delete;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfSecondname;

    @FXML
    void search(ActionEvent event) {

 if (tfSearch.getText().equals("")){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Enter firstname please !!!");
    }else{
    if(checkName()){
   search();

}else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"firstname does not exist");
}

    } 

    }


    @FXML
    void deleteRecord(ActionEvent event) {
 try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            String sql;
            sql="delete from sstudent where firstname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";
            int result=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Record deleted sucessfully");
            tfSearch.setText(null);
            tfFirstname.setText(null);
            tfSecondname.setText(null);
            cbGender.setValue(null);
            tfLocation.setText(null);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to delete record "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void updateRecord(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }


        try{
            String sql;
            sql="update sstudent set secondname='"+tfSecondname.getText()+"',"
            +"location='"+tfLocation.getText()+"',"
            +"gender='"+cbGender.getValue().toString()+"'"
            +" where firstname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";


            int result=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Record updated sucessfully");
       } catch (SQLException f) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to update record "+f.getMessage()); 
       }


    }

    @FXML
    void insertRecord(ActionEvent event) {
try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
                  stmt=con.createStatement();  
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
                }


    try {
    String sql;
    sql="insert into sstudent(firstname,secondname,gender,location) values ("
      +"'"+tfFirstname.getText()+"',"
      +"'"+tfSecondname.getText()+"',"
      +"'"+cbGender.getValue().toString()+"',"
      +"'"+tfLocation.getText()+"')";

    int result=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"record saved sucessfully ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to insert record "+e.getMessage());
    }


    }


      private boolean checkName(){
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }
         try{
             String sql;
             sql="select * from sstudent where firstname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";
             rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             if(rs.next()){
             return true;
             }
         }catch (SQLException e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"unable to retrieve record"+ e.getMessage());
         }
         return false;
         }

      private void search(){
       try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            String sql;
            sql = "select * from sstudent where firstname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
             tfFirstname.setText(rs.getString("firstname"));
             tfSecondname.setText(rs.getString("secondname"));
             cbGender.setValue(rs.getString("gender"));
             tfLocation.setText(rs.getString("location"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to retrieve record "+e.getMessage());
        }   
      }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {



      cbGender.getItems().addAll("male","female");
    }    

}
```

```
//main class....
package fxapplication;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author PHILSERVER
 */
public class FXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("search.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

// my scene builder forms....
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="fxapplication.SearchController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="24.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="347.0" prefWidth="549.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tfSearch" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="firstname" />
            <Button layoutX="366.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#search" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="search" />
            <Button fx:id="delete" layoutX="342.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteRecord" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="delete" />
            <Button fx:id="update" layoutX="185.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#updateRecord" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="update" />
            <Button fx:id="insert" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#insertRecord" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="insert" />
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="76.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="firstname" />
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="125.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="secondname" />
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="174.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="gender" />
            <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="location" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfFirstname" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfSecondname" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfLocation" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="218.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbGender" layoutX="185.0" layoutY="170.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" promptText="&lt;select gender&gt;" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you post a complete JavaFX application, but the actual question is how to create the table in mysql? "sstudent(firstname,secondname,gender,location)"

Comment: no i just want to add,update,delete and search record in tableview in javafx..with mysql..the codes i posted was codes,from my scenebuilder to the database(mysql) i taught that will help if you want to connect tableview to the database(mysql).. so that you can help me with that

Comment: But there is no `TableView` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: (Off-topic: Don't use a `JOptionPane` in JavaFX. This will hang on many systems. Use an [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) instead.)

Comment: If you use direct JDBC, then you are responsible for converting the data in the ResultSet to what the (missing) TableView wants; Java beans. You could make it easier by using JPA (Eclipselink) or EBean to do the mapping for you.